# Solution for refurbishing sealed switches

Tags: switches, cleaning

I don't know if this is the right stack to ask this in, but I could not find a match, but I feel this question may have enough common interest to find a solution anyway.

I am attempting to refurbish some old switches which can no longer be found. The problem is the switches are sealed by plastic rivets, so I cannot actually disassemble them, well I could, but I could only do it once ;)

The problem is oil has penetrated many of the switches, which leads to a lack of audible click and poor electrical connection. I have had a little success with ultrasonically cleaning in IPA, but the problem is getting the residue out of the switch.

The switches are ABS, and the contacts are nickle and gold coated copper. Do I have any hope in getting the oils out of the switch? Will I need to resort to degreasers, and if so, what can I use that would be safe to all the material types?

Comment: Have you considered switch cleaner? Comes in an aerosol can.

Comment: Submerge them in something that can dissolve the oil, pull a vacuum. Now you have diluted oil and solvent inside the switch. Just need a way to get it out.

Comment: dismantle one switch (watch out for the little springs that go *sprooooing* and disappear under a cupboard). Plastic rivets can often be reset with a soldering iron, or replaced with screws. Then with that intelligence, decide whether you can dismantle and reassemble the others.